# Add Slide to CuteSlider Dynamically Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, slider

I have problem to add dynamically slide to CuteSlider.and I hope someone here can help me to fix this.i know a lot of related topic created on Stackoverflow.com but none of them solve my problem.
I used these 4 link in my head:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/cute/cute.slider.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/cute/cute.transitions.all.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And here it is my Cute Slider code:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper" >
    <div id="slider" class="cute-slider" data-width="800" data-height="350" data-force="" >
        <ul id="parentslider2" data-type="slides">
            <li data-delay="4" data-trans3d="tr2,tr20,tr57" data-trans2d="tr1,tr14,tr26">
                <img src="images/1.png" data-thumb="images/thumbs/1.png " />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my jquery script, its not working:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    function makeDiv(number) {
        $("#parentslider").append("<li data-delay='4' data-trans3d='tr2,tr20,tr57' data-trans2d='tr1,tr14,tr26'><img src='images/" + number + ".png'        data-thumb='images/thumbs/1.png '/></li>")
    };

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { 
         makeDiv(i); 
    }   
});
```

I think I need my script to load before everything else and then my page load but i'm not certain how to do that or even its right solution.i can make everything else outside of these slider and worked perfectly(by jquery of course) but i don't know why when i try do something inside slider nothing worked at all.
I really appreciate if anyone have solution and help me out.

Comment: Does it enter into the window.load function at all? "its not working" do you get any error messages in the console ?

Comment: about question i have to say "Yes,I think so". and i don't get any error messages. i don't know why, but this script worked perfectly out of slider div.

Comment: Can u reproduce this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: unfortunately not working on "jsfiddle".but if you want can send it as zip file.

Comment: Can u provide me the jsfiddle link..?

Comment: i try a few time but can't run on "Jsfiddle" ,any way i put all file inside one folder and upload it here(http://mahvashdolatabadi.ir/test/Template 2.rar)  , i really appreciate if see it and give me a some solution for my problem.